# How to build a php extensions from tgz file using make?

Tags: php, mongodb, makefile, pecl

### Background

I use a RedHat machine without root access, no access to the yum packet manager and no Docker support. This is the policy unfortunately at my work.

I have configured Apache and PHP using a tar file in a folder. Also done same for MongoDB,  now I try to configure the PHP drivers for MongoDB according to these instructions:

https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php/

However I get stuck on the first bullet:

`sudo pecl install mongodb`

### Problem

Do I need PECL? Can the extension be downloaded manually, and added to PHP?

I have tried to download the mongodb extension manually from:
https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

How to compile it mongodb.so? I tried to run pecl on a machine where I have root access then I saw it downloaded the mongodb-1.10.0.tgz and run make (in output when installing).

When I unpack the tgz file manually, I am not able to run make. How to use the makefile.frag? How to run make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link on how to build mongodb.so:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php

```
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver.git
cd mongo-php-driver
git submodule update --init
phpize
./configure
make all
sudo make install
```

You can also unpack the mongodb-1.10.0.tgz file with:

```
tar -xvf mongodb-1.10.0.tgz
phpize
make all
sudo make install
```

Comment: Do you know if pecl add any extra flags to configure? That I might miss if I do it manually?

Comment: I think its uses default, but it is just a guess from my side.

Comment: I found the documentation for it here how to do it offline:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php